# Ping server until read to login via RDP and attempt to login

Tags: windows, rdp, ping

Looking for a way via powershell or any means to ping until server is available and once it is then run remote desktop to login.
I have seen it before but unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: You're gonna have a bad time trying to do this because there's no guarantee that RDP is ready for connections even though the host is pingable. Particularly post reboot after hotfixes, it can be minutes before RDP will accept connections even though the network stack is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna give this a quick shot from memory via BATCH.

Save batch file, for example as `TSWait.bat`
Execute as `TSWait.bat <serverIP / Hostname>`

`@ECHO OFF
SET ARG1=%1
IF "%ARG1%" EQU "" (
ECHO You forgot to specify the server IP or hostname.
GOTO END
)
ECHO Waiting for %ARG1% to come online...
:LOOP
PING -n 1 -w 1 %ARG1% | find "bytes=32" > NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO LOOP
ECHO Starting RDP connection to %ARG1%
START MSTSC.EXE /v:%ARG1%
:END`